# How can I ensure that open source code I'm using is not malicious?

Tags: security, open-source

I was wondering how can I be sure about safety of code in open source projects, particularly the ones with thousands lines of code, including calls to `popen()` or `system()`.
How can I know there is no harmful and malicious code in there?
Is there anyway I can examine the code safely?

Comment: That's what open source *means*: you're able to examine the code

Comment: How can you be sure of the safety of any code? This is hardly limited to open source. In a nutshell, you can't, not with 100% certainty. At least with open source you can examine the code yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering how can I be sure about safety of codes in open source projects

The short answer is that you can't.

Yes, in theory, you could go through the whole code base and audit it, which you can't with proprietary code, but who has got time for that?  On the other hand, a lot of the bigger projects tend to have large numbers of volunteer contributors eyeballing the code all the time and the organisations that run them (e.g. Apache and GNU) have ostensibly benign motivations, so I think, malicious code would probably be found and flagged pretty quickly.

Having said that, I can think of [one totally disastrous security flaw](http://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571) that affected Open Source software and was not detected for two years.  It arose precisely *because* it was possible for a third party to modify an insanely complex (and badly written) open source product.  The person making the modification did not understand what they were doing.  Who'd have thought that was possible when they can read the code...

Answer (score 3):

You can never be 100% sure of the safety of any code of any project, open-source or not.  When using any code or software you did not write yourself, you inevitably assume a certain level of trust of the third-party author(s).  If the project is open-source, you can audit their code to your heart's content, but as other responders have already pointed out, it is unlikely that you will have the time/resources to perform a full, line-by-line inspection.

You might find Ken Thompson's "Reflections on Trusting Trust" article an interesting read for further reflection on issues like this:

http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html

Answer (score 2):

Because it is open source, you can examine the code. As can others, so the safety is potentially much better than that of closed source, where a (very) limited number of people see the code. Your version control system (git) calculates checksums to detect changed code.

Often looking for ten minutes at the source code is enough to decide not to trust software. Where there are many alternatives, that suffices.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use git for open source software now?  I didn't get that memo.

Comment: No, it is not compulsory. If you want to ensure the code wasn't changed, checksums can help. Git calculates them in a way that can help. I haven't checked to see which other vcs do

Answer (score 1):

I should also add that apparent (and, in theory, verifiable) lack of malicious code in open-source projects does not guarantee their safety.

The reason is **security bugs** exploitable by malicious input.

For example, your favorite open-source picture/document/whatever viewer (or web browser) can have one or more of those bugs. If you open a maliciously crafted file with it, you can get pwned.

While I cannot definitively state that open-source software has more security bugs than commercial software, I'd warn you that if it's not an extremely popular project and if nobody's responsible with their money for the security defects in it leading to you getting pwned, chances are there are such bugs and there are very few people who are interested in and fixing them. I mean, programmers love to build. It's fun. Security is hard and often secondary to that.

Comment: -1 FUD. The people responsible with their money mostly don't see the code.

Comment: @StephanEggermont: That distinction doesn't invalidate the statement. You should consider the entity/organization as a whole.

Comment: no that is a fundamental security error. Weakest chain. Most commercial organisations, and especially banks and insurance companies, are organised so that they can assign blame instead of creating secure software

Comment: @StephanEggermont: Most = all? Also, did Microsoft not have a "security push", which probably wasn't initiated by the rank and file programmers?

Comment: @StephanEggermont, I suspect you don't undestand insurance or banking very well. Insurers will put lots of conditions in place and work with the customer to reduce the risk. This helps them to charge lower premiums compared to competing insurers and hence retain the customer. Banks have the same incentive to reduce losses - if they have lower losses than other banks they can give better interest while also making higher profits. Banks and insurers have been responsible for pushing improved security standards in large corporations. Ever heard of PCI?